# Sumifs from an Array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to do a sumif from an array but i am not sure how to reference a full column in an array. For instance i have the following data in excel (in columns A and B) and code that works fine,

`RR TT
1   J
2   K
3   J
4   K
5   J
5   K
6   J
7   K
8   J
9   K`

```
 Sub test() 
 Dim s As Range 
 Dim s2 As Range
 Set s = Range("A2:A11") 
 Set s2 = Range("B2:B11")
 e = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(s, s2, "J")
 MsgBox e 
 End Sub
```

This sums the RR column where the TT column equals "J" and the answer is 23. But in the code i assign each column to a seperate Range in VBA. I would like to assign both columns to an array and do the sumifs from the array. The first part of the code would then look as follows,

```
Dim s() As Variant
ReDim s(1 To 10, 1 To 2)
s = Range("A2:B11")
```

How do i then reference the columns of the array in the sumifs function? (the first two entries in the sumifs function)

```
e = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(?, ?, "J")
```

I will at the end work with a much bigger dataset and if it is possible i would like not create a ton of seperate Ranges but just one array.

Comment: You can't - SUMIF(S) doesn't work with arrays, only ranges.

Comment: As @Rory wrote, you cannot.  You'll need to write your own, looping through the array.

Comment: Why do you want to use arrays anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom function to do this:

```
Public Function SumIf(lookupTable() As Variant, lookupValue As String) As Long
    Dim I As Long

    SumIf = 0

    For I = LBound(lookupTable) To UBound(lookupTable)
        If lookupTable(I, 1) = lookupValue Then
            SumIf = SumIf + lookupTable(I, 2)
        End If
    Next I
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub M_snb()
  msgbox [sum((A1:A9)*(B1:B9="J"))]
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub M_snb()
  msgbox [sumproduct((A1:A9)*(B1:B9="J"))]
end sub
```

or

```
Sub M_snb()
  msgbox [sum(if(B1:B9="J",A1:A9,0))]
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and the answers. I don't have to use arrays but it was my first choice and keeping with ranges is fine. I did find got it right with Ranges. And i did the following

```
 Sub test() 
 Dim s As Range 
 Set s = Range("A2:B11") 
 e = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(s.Columns(1), s.Columns(2), "J")
 MsgBox e 
 End Sub
```

This also gives me what i want.